# can i connect two (usb to serial eg. FTDI)?

Tags: fpga, uart

Is it possible to connect/communicate in following manner?

(FPGA-1) to (USB to serial-1) to (USB cable) to (usb_to serial-2) to FPGA-2. So the FPGA-1 sends data from uart Tx..then (USB to serial-1) receives and converts to (USB signal) ..sends this via usb cable to (USB to serial-2)...then this is received by FPGA-2 using the uart Rx.

If not, is there something else i could use in this manner? thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want to connect uart Tx to uart Rx? Distance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you’d be using an FT232 or equivalent. The answer is no, you cannot directly connect them as they are USB **device** only and you’d need one of them to be a USB **host**.

I know of no serial to USB host chips.

What you could use is on one end is a microcontroller with USB host capabilities. This would, of course, require the appropriate programming to act as a bridge.

Answer (score 1):

A USB-to-Serial is more than just direct connections - it has abilities to change baud rate, etc, meaning that it has an active component (an IC) thus you can't connect 2 together passively and hope to get the same signal out. To use them both you *need* a host running to not only power both converters, but also pass the data between them. It would be much easier to configure the same baud rate on both FPGAs and connect the Tx to the other one's Rx and vice versa. If you have distance issues, I recommend perhaps using an amplifier to keep the signal strong, but to use USB to serial converters is a very convoluted way of achieving serial communication between 2 serial devices. It's like sending an email to someone, but at the exchange server, they physically print it out, read it, and re-type it into a new email and send it to the recipient.